# I've been archiving an iOS inhouse app,but the Xcode continuous complaining an error

Tags: ios, xcode

When I archiving an iOS in-house app, the Xcode always report an error:error: /Users/Developername/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-ghaoxlfmcjlaeabaeitlddhtexff/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/appname_inhouse/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/appname.app: No such file or directory.How could I resolve this problem ,i'm going crazy about it, your answer will be very appreciated!

Comment: Look at the build results. There will be a lot more detail about whatever errors are preventing the build from succeeding.

Comment: I can't tell anything from build results, cause the results always changes,  but finally I got my problem solved, it turns out that I didn't check out fully version of my app's code,it almost drives me crazy.Anyway thank you for your answer.